# Recreating this image as a displaystyle formula

Tags: equations

I have this image which I would like to recreate as a displaystyle equation

[image]

I know how to do everything except the curved arrow with the text, this is what I was able to produce.

```
$$2H_2O_2\longrightarrow2H_2O+O_2$$
```

If this isn't possible to do with equations can you suggest a package which can create this?

Comment: For reference, see [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Comment: Is that a standard chemical notation? Perhaps you can achieve it with Tikz, meanwhile you can check [this](http://www.mychemistry.eu/mychemistry/) that could be interesting for you... I hope.

Comment: @Aradnix It's some weird notation used once by my book

Comment: @KristofferRyhl  If you use it only once and it is not a standard symbol, then you must explain it. If you must explain it, you might as well just use a plain arrow and add the explanation. Introducing a new symbol for a single use is not likely to improve the exposition. You can put some text above the plain arrow using `\xrightarrow{text}` (from the `amsmath` package).

Comment: @Dan I'm transcriping a scanned page, but I agree

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy wth `pst-node` and the `mhchem` package:

```
\documentclass[pdf]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{sansmath}

\begin{document}

\sansmath
\[ \psset{linewidth=0.6pt, arrows = ->, nodesep = 3pt, colsep = 1.2cm, npos = 0.45, arrowinset=0}
\begin{psmatrix}
2\ce{H2O2} & 2\ce{H2O} +\ce{O2}
 \ncline{1,1}{1,2}\naput[labelsep=0.25]{\psarc{->}{0.25}{180}{380}}\naput[labelsep=4ex]{\textsf{Katalase}}
\end{psmatrix} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Kristoffer Ryhl: See my updated answer. Note that you can compile with `pdflatex` provided you use the `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX) or `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX) switch.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `tikz` method with options to customize the thickness and colors of the arrow and text (you can provide the chemistry):

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\MyArrowWithCircleLength}{0.7cm}
\newcommand*{\MyArrowWithCircle}[2][]{%
    % #1 = draw options
    % #2 = node text
    \,\tikz[baseline,overlay] 
        \draw [->, #1] (0,0.75ex) -- ++(\MyArrowWithCircleLength+2pt,0)
            node [anchor=south,->, midway, yshift=0.5*\MyArrowWithCircleLength, #1, draw=none]   {#2};
    \tikz[baseline]
        \draw [->, #1] (0,0.5*\MyArrowWithCircleLength+0.75ex) arc (0:180:-0.5*\MyArrowWithCircleLength);         
\,%
}

\begin{document}
\[ 
 A \MyArrowWithCircle[thick,draw=red, text=red]{\tiny Katalase} B \MyArrowWithCircle[thin,draw=blue]{\tiny Katalase} C
\]
\end{document}
```